# How was Sun created as per Vedas? Anyway to reconcile the different creation accounts?

Tags: vedas, surya, vedic-gods, creation

Different Vedas seem to make different claims about how the Sun was created:

### Breath of god

> Atharva Veda 19.27.7 “**With vital breath the Gods produced the Sun** whose face turn every way.”

### Eye of Brahma/Purusha

> Yajur Veda 31.12 “The Moon was gendered from his mind, and **from his eye the Sun had birth…”**

### Vritra

> Atharva Veda 4.10.5 “From ocean sprang the Amulet, from **Vritra sprang the Lord of Day (Sun)....."**

### Indra

> Rig Veda 2.12.7 “…**He who gave being to the Sun** and Morning, who leads the waters, He, O men, is Indra.”

### Soma

> Rig Veda 9.42.1 “**ENGENDERING the Sun in floods,** engendering heaven’s lights, green-hued, Robed in the waters and the milk.”
>
> Rig Veda 9.96.5 “Father of holy hymns, Soma flows onward the Father of the earth, Father of heaven: Father of Agni, **Sūrya’s generator,** the Father who begat Indra and Viṣṇu.”

### Dhatar

> Rig Veda 10.190.3 “Dhātar, the great Creator, **then formed in due order Sun** and Moon…”

Given this, how was the Sun actually created? Is there a way to reconcile the above contradictions?

Comment: Are you asking how to reconcile these contradictory statements? What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rig Vedic mantras contain **multi-layered** meanings, as they were composed by the Sages in a poetic and cryptic manner.  Sun that was mentioned in Rig Vedic mantras, may be referring to Physical Sun or DIVINE Savitr or the ATMA or Soul that resides in every individual.

---

The following is an excerpt from the teachings of Sri Ramana Maharshi.

> Mr. Douglas Ainslie (Mr. Grant Duff), an aristocratic English
>   gentleman, 70 years old, nephew of a former Governor of Madras, an
>   author and poet formerly attached to the British Legation in Athens,
>   Paris and The Hague, had come to Madras as a guest of Government
>   House. He came to see Maharshi with a letter of introduction from Paul
>   Brunton.
>
> He expressed a desire to hear the Vedas. On Monday a letter arrived
>   from Riga and the questions therein happened to coincide with the
>   questions the European visitor had asked relating to the existence of
>   departed souls and how best to serve them.
>
> The reply sent to Riga was read out to him. Tamil songs from
>   Maharshi’s “Truth Revealed” and the Vedas were repeated in his
>   presence. He considered the recitations magnificent.
>
> He came the next afternoon and to the wonder of others, had an
>   experience on the previous night which he repeated to Maharshi. It was
>   that he had seen something like an electric **light within himself**
>   in the heart centre on the right side. ***And he added further that he
>   had seen the sun shining within.***
>
> Maharshi smiled a little and then had a translation of “Atmavidya”
>   (Self-Knowledge) read out to him wherein there is the cryptic saying
>   that realisation consists in reaching the Atman (Self) which is the
>   expanse of consciousness (chidvyoman) as distinguished from the mind,
>   which is the expansion of chittavyoman.
>
> This explanation appealed to him.

---

One should have practical experience in SPIRITUAL realm, to understand the cryptic language of Veda.

Comment: @Sanatan Darshan, think of God (Brahman) as a conscious organism which is the sum total of all existence (including reality and imagination) , an organism for which there is no OUTSIDE but only INSIDE. Think with His point of view, and perhaps you may get the Vedas. Remember they are not contradictory, but the same words have varying meanings per context.

Comment: @SanatanDarshan The Vedas in Tamil are called 'Marai' - literally meaning 'Hide'. Because they hide the truth in plain sight. Simply reading it won't give you the meaning, let alone reading translations. The hidden meanings are protected by gurus who only reveal it to the humble, open-minded and deserving.